# Help with reversing a string in C

Tags: c

I am trying to reverse a character string in C

Here is what I have

```
void reverse(char str[]) {
    int i = 0;

    int length;
    // Get string length
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0' ; ++i) {
        length = i;
    }

    char reversed[1000];

    int j;
    j = 0;
    // Reverse it
    for (j = 0; j < length ; ++j) {
        reversed[j] = str[length - j];
    }

}
```

I know that `reversed` contains the string reversed, but I'm not sure how to modify the original `str` without throwing away data I need.

I also don't know how to set `str`to `reversed` without looping *again*.

Would it be acceptable to do another...

```
    int m;
    m = 0;

    for (m = 0; m < length ; ++m) {
        str[j] = reversed[j];
    }
```

Usually I'd say this many loops smells, but I'm also still quite unfamiliar with the language so I'm not sure...

### Update

Thanks for all the answers guys, and I appreciate the edits too!

I ended up going with [this](http://codepad.org/tQmMFzFq)...

```
int main() {

 char str[] = "Reverse me!";

 int length;

 for (length = 0; str[length] != '\0'; length++) {

 }

 printf("length => %d chars\n", length);

 int j, k;
 char c;

 for (j = 0, k = length - 1; j < k; j++, k--) {
  c = str[k];    
  str[k] = str[j];
  str[j] = c;
 } 

 printf("reversed => %s\n", str);

 return 0;
}
```

Some things I now know...

- There is a `strlen()` like in PHP. However, it has not been discussed in the book yet, plus I need to get familiar with null terminated strings.
- A `for` loop can assign and do multiple things that are comma separated. I never knew this!

So asking was worthwhile :)

Comment: Please mark Homework with the [homework] tag.  Also, please search.  This is asked very, very frequently.

Comment: @S.Lott This isn't homework, well at least not for any educational faculty. This is for my own interests. Also, since I'm new to C, I wasn't sure what I should be searching for. But if it's a duplicate, let me know so I can vote to close. Thanks

Comment: See your copy of K&R2, page 62.

Comment: @schot Ah, there it is! I wish I could have figured it out on my own though...

Comment: @alex: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reverse+string+%5Bc%5D.  All of these.  It's not hard to use the SO search.

Comment: @S.Lott OK thanks, but what I *really* wanted was for someone to tell me if I was going down the right track. I guess that is hard to do on SO, so my apologies.

Comment: @alex: To see if you're going down the right track, read other solutions.  Reading other people's code is a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments on your code:

```
void reverse(char str[]) {
    int i = 0;

    int length;
    // Get string length
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0' ; ++i) {
        length = i;
    }
```

Rather than copying the i to length every time you could just wait until the end.

```
size_t len = 0; // size_t is an unsigned integer that is large enough to hold the sizes
                // of the biggest things you can have (32 bits on 32 bit computer,
                // 64 bits on a 64 bit computer)
char * s = str;
while (*s) {
    len++;
    s++;
}
```

Though the compiler would probably be able to make this optimization for you.

You should know, though, that there is a standard string function `strlen` ( `#include  <string.h>` )which will measure the length of a char string using the same general algorithm (look for the end) but is usually optimized for the target processor.

```
len = strlen(str);
```

Your code again:

```
    char reversed[1000];
```

Using big arrays are good for learning and simple examples, but you can also allocate memory dynamically based on the size you now know you need.  The standard function for doing this is `malloc` which is in `stdlib.h` (also in `malloc.h`).  Memory allocated with this function should also be freed, though.

```
int * p = malloc( 8 * sizeof(int) ); // allocate an array of 8 ints
/* ... work on p ... */
free(p);
/* ... don't access the memory pointed to by p anymore ... */
p = 0;
```

There are also other functions in the malloc family.  There's `calloc`, which allocates memory and clears sets it to 0.  There is also a function called `strdup` (which isn't in standard C, but is very widely available in string.h) which takes a string and allocates a duplicate of it.  It is really just:

```
char * strdup(const char * str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char * s = malloc(len+1);
    if (!s) {
        return s;
    }
    return strcpy(s,str); // This could have been memcpy since you know the size
                          // and memcpy might have been faster on many processors
}
```

Another useful memory allocation function is `alloca` (not in the C standard, but widely available and similar functionality is available with variable length arrays in C99).  It is great, but works differently from `malloc`.  It allocates memory that is only useable until the current function returns because this memory is allocated in the same way as memory for local variables (from the stack).

More of your code:

```
    int j;
    j = 0;
    // Reverse it
    for (j = 0; j < length ; ++j) {
        reversed[j] = str[length - j];
    }
```

The code:

```
void reverse_in_place(char * str, size_t len) {
   size_t i, j;
   for (i = 0, j = len - 1; i < j ; i++, j--) {
        char a = str[i];
        char z = str[j];
        str[i] = z;
        str[j] = a;
   }
}
```

should swap the order of the string without making a copy of it.  For strings with odd length it won't try to swap the middle char with itself.

Comment: Hey, this is a great answer, exactly what I was looking for! I realised the first thing shortly after I posted the question, so I made the `for` block empty.

Comment: Just a couple of things you may want to attend to. (1) strdup/alloca are not standard C (you should mention this). (2) Both your strdup and your reverse_in_place are buggy (with off-by-one errors). The first doesn't allocate enough space and the second gives you an empty string.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks! Fixed them.  `reverse_in_place` without the `- 1` in `j = len -1` would have moved the null terminator to `str[0]` making it an empty string.  The `strdup` without the `+ 1` in the call to `malloc` would not have allocated space for the null terminator. I feel silly for having made those errors.

Answer (score 4):

You want to do an *in-place* reversal. Here's a standard algorithm:

```
// taken from The C Programming Language
//    by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie (K&R)
void reverse(char s[])
{
      int c, i, j;

      for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
         c = s[i];
         s[i] = s[j];
         s[j] = c;
      }
}
```

Note that `strlen` pretty much replaces your original first loop. It's one of the many standard string manipulation routines available from `string.h`.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/In-place algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)
- [Wikipedia/`string.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String.h)
- [Wikipedia/C Standard Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)

Comment: An exact copy of K&R2, page 62 ;)

Comment: Putting strlen() in a loop's termination condition is a handy way to make a quadratic algorithm out of a linear one. Call it once and store the result in a variable.

Comment: @ceo Haha, that made me smile!

Comment: @ceo, yes, it would make it quadratic, if it were actually _in_ the condition section. I think you'll find it's in the initialisation section here.

Comment: @paxdiablo: how right you are. That'll teach me to read the code carefully before I open my fool mouth.

Comment: @ceo I skipped over that too!

Answer (score 4):

You can use either of the two methods below, depending on whether you're comfortable with pointers or not. It will also be worthwhile looking at them side-by-side when you satrt learning about pointers so you can better understand how they map to each other.

This is a full program for testing purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// The pointer version.
void reverse1 (char *str) {
    char t;                      // Temporary char for swapping.
    char *s = str;               // First character of string.
    char *e = &(s[strlen(s)-1]); // Last character of string.

    // Swap first and last character the move both pointers
    // towards each other. Stop when they meet or cross.
    while (s < e) {
        t = *s;
        *s++ = *e;
        *e-- = t;
    }
}

// The array version.
void reverse2 (char *str) {
    char t;                // Temporary char for swapping.
    int s = 0;             // First character of string.
    int e = strlen(str)-1; // Last character of string.

    // Swap first and last character the move both pointers
    // towards each other. Stop when they meet or cross.
    while (s < e) {
        t = str[s];
        str[s++] = str[e];
        str[e--] = t;
    }
}
```

```
int main (void) {
    char x[] = "This is a string for reversing.";
    printf ("Original: [%s]\n", x);
    reverse1 (x);
    printf ("Reversed: [%s]\n", x);
    reverse2 (x);
    printf ("   Again: [%s]\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
Original: [This is a string for reversing.]
Reversed: [.gnisrever rof gnirts a si sihT]
   Again: [This is a string for reversing.]
```

Comment: This looks great, but I'm not up to pointers yet. Anyway, thanks, it looks efficient.

Comment: @alex, I've added a non-pointer version since you're not yet comfortable with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a string in C using pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
char *srcptr = "Hello!";
char *destptr;
unsigned int length = 0;
void main(void)
{
   while(*(ptr++) != '\0')
   {
       length++;
   }
   //at the end of while loop, pointer points to end of string 
   while(length--)
   {
        *destptr++ = *ptr--;
   }
    //append null at the end
    *destptr = '\0';
    printf("%s",ptr);
 }
```